# Apk crashes after adding realm to react native

Tags: android, react-native, realm

Thanks in advance.

I tried to install Realm 3.3.0 on react native and after generating the build when the app opens it crashes. I use

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5"
```

**My gradle are**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I put up the log cat and i am getting the following;

```
beginning of crash
2019-10-24 18:07:16.929 11412-11498/com.xxxxx.xxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
Process: com.xxxx.xxxxx, PID: 11412
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: librealmreact.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:738)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:591)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:529)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:484)
at io.realm.react.RealmReactModule.<clinit>(RealmReactModule.java:56)
at io.realm.react.RealmReactPackage.createNativeModules(RealmReactPackage.java:31)
at com.facebook.react.ReactPackageHelper.getNativeModuleIterator(ReactPackageHelper.java:42)
at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:41)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:1215)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackages(ReactInstanceManager.java:1185)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1123)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$900(ReactInstanceManager.java:124)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:948)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Is there any work around for this ??

Comment: How did you add realm? What steps you follow for adding realm? Which version of realm? Does the same happens on IOS?

Comment: @cutiko
1) npm install --save realm
2) react-native link realm
3) added project in setting gradle
4) added implementation in build.gradle.
5) Modified the MainApplication.java 

Build is success, when open the app it craches.

Comment: @cutiko in package json Ihave 
"realm": "^3.0.0",

I tried even with 3.3.0

Comment: @cutiko i only use android.

Answer (score 3):

I use realm in my daily work, I have met this issue is because realm doesn't support hermes engine yet, see this [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/2455), you need to change `enableHermes` to false in file android/app/build.gradle

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,
]
```

if you are using 0.60.0 or greater version the step to install realm is

1. `npm i realm`
2. `npx react-native link realm`, realm's autolink is not working yet, yes, you need link manually with command
3. `npx jetify`

no need to edit MainAplication.java or other file to link more

Comment: When i turned hermes to false then I get
``java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so``

Comment: @AnkitJayaprakash is it your project from 0.5x.y then upgraded to 0.6x.y version? then see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57036317/react-native-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-find-dso-to-load-libherm
probably you are not upgrade it properly