# React Native Android: Release build keeps crashing since

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react native--new to app development in general in fact. I am trying to run a release build on Android emulator but the app just keeps crashing.

The debug version runs without any problem, and on iOS the same release build runs perfectly.

Here are what I did:

1.Cleaned the build folder

2.Created index.android.bundle at android/app/src/main/assets

3.Created release APK file

4.Ran on Android simulator, but keeps crashing.

I am lost here. Could someone help out and tell me where I possibly went wrong?

Here is by android/app/build.gradle:

```
    import com.android.build.OutputFile


    apply plugin: "com.android.application"
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


    project.ext.react = [
        enableHermes: false
    ]

    apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
    apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
    apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"


    def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


    def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true


    def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

    def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

    //Function to get key from the key store

    def getPassword(String currentUser, String keyChain) {
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def stderr = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'security', '-q', 'find-generic-password', '-a', currentUser, '-s', keyChain, '-w'
        standardOutput = stdout
        errorOutput = stderr
        ignoreExitValue true
    }
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        stdout.toString().trim()
    }

    def pass = getPassword("my_name","my_keystore");

    android {
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.myappid"
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true 
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        splits {
            abi {
                reset()
                enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
                universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
                include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
            }
        }
        signingConfigs {
            debug {
                storeFile file('debug.keystore')
                storePassword 'android'
                keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
                keyPassword 'android'
            }
            release {
                storeFile file('release.keystore')
                storePassword pass 
                keyAlias 'release'
                keyPassword pass 
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
            release {
                // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
                // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
                shrinkResources true
            }
        }

        packagingOptions {
            pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so"
            pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so"
            pickFirst "lib/x86/libc++_shared.so"
            pickFirst "lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so"
        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }


        // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
                def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
                def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                            versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                }

            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
        
        debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
        debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
            exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        }
        debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
            exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        }
        addUnimodulesDependencies([exclude: ['expo-splash-screen','expo-permissions']])

        if (enableHermes) {
            def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
            debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
            releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
        } else {
            implementation jscFlavor
        }
    }

    // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
    // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
    task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.compile
        into 'libs'
    }

    apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Here is the error log from adb logcat:
[image: ADB Logcat Error Log]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your issue from your error log is related to this...

[React-Native :java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57036317/react-native-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-find-dso-to-load-libherm)

Answer (score 0):

Open Build.gradle from android/app.

Change enableProguardInReleaseBuilds to false,

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

clean the gradle and try