# Release app crash FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native

I can build in debug mode, it works fine, but when I get release build, it gets build, but the application breaks, you can see the error output here.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.

FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
Process: com.example, PID: 27990
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(Unknown Source:2)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(Unknown Source:10)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(Unknown Source:18)
at com.facebook.react.q.q(Unknown Source:180)
at com.facebook.react.q.b(Unknown Source:0)
at com.facebook.react.q$e.run(Unknown Source:68)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

"react-native": "0.62.2"

Comment: any workaround?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57036317/7178860 This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63048532/7178860

Answer (score 0):

This is a 0.62.2 version issue [that was solved here.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30761)

Long story short,
Edit ../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle with [this fix](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/53f55001afbf07494de0df064a92dfdd42f37c98)